# Create a bash date/time variable from argument

Tags: bash, datetime, bsd

Given an argument being passed in like this:

```
~/Documents/checkout/check-out.sh potatoes '2013/05/22 13:43:00'
```

Using 1st or 2nd line, produces

```
st=`date --date "$2" +%s`                   # mogul's suggestion
st=$(date --date="$2" +%s)                  # Kent's suggestion
st=$(date --date="2013/05/22 14:45:00" +%s)

date: illegal option -- -
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
    [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OS X's version of `date` doesn't understand the `--date` option; you need to use `-f` and give it the format of the input date:

```
st=$(date -j -f "%Y/%m/%d %T" "$2" +%s)
```

For example:

```
$ date -j -f "%Y/%m/%d %T" "2013/05/22 14:45:00" +%s
1369259100
```

Comment: Brilliant. I just learned there's a difference between BSD and GNU.

Comment: Heh, I posted a link to the BSD date and still totally missed the `-f` option, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Your OSX ships with a [`BSD date`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/date.1.html), not `GNU date`, so there are no GNU-style options (you can install `GNU date` via macports or homebrew).

Comment: According to man date, -d is to set the kernels value for daylight savings time.

Comment: You are of course right, I didn't read the manpage closely enough, but I just remembered that only GNU date has the `--date` feature, so you need to install it using macports or homebrew.

Comment: Yep, just keep in mind that `GNU date` also has a (completely different) `-f` option, so this is a portability nightmare in case you are writing scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
x='2013/05/22 13:43:00'
st=`date --date "$x" +%s`
```

seems to work here. or in your case it should be

```
st=`date --date "$2" +%s`
```

Comment: Ahh, your `date` seems to be a different version than the one I have. Please describe your system.

Comment: I'm seeing that the option shouldn't be -d. Reading the man date doesn't make it much clearer though.

Comment: Apologies for not including BSD in the question. I appreciate the attempt.

Comment: No worries, seems Gordon got it worked out, not that I can easily test he's solution...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
st=$(date --date="$2" +%s)
```

Comment: Apologies for not including BSD in the question.